# Weird header issue

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Im working on a wordpress site and I cant figure out the issue with a huge div that will occasionally get inserted into the header.

It seems to be caused by a chat widget called Zopium.

Attached is a screenshot example of what happens.

Link to the site: http://fitness.pixelworklab.com/

This is the code that gets injected:

```
    <div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 100%;">
<embed id="__zopnetworkswf" src="http://cdn.zopim.com/swf/ZClientController2.swf" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="position: absolute; top: -50px; left: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden;" wmode="opaque"></div>
```

This is what is seen in the console:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to recreate the issue on your site. Can you give more info on when it happens? Does it happen when you're logged out of your WordPress account?

Comment: @js111 Have you fixed it yet?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced some "weird" stuff from times when I called `wp_head();` in the template header but forgot to call `wp_footer();` at the end of the page.

As the issue didn't happened to @shennan (as he said on comments) and neither to me as we both were not logged into wp-admin, I believe there is a great chance this could be the issue.

So, check your template footer for `wp_footer();`. If it isn't there, implement it and test the result.

Hope it helps.